# Flutter Firebase.initializeApp error: "Nonnull field "projectId" is null" when projectId is not null

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am using firebase for my flutter project and wanted to initialize it with this code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'intranet_app',
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

The options are generated from flutterfire configure and all fields are already filled (apiKey, appId, projectId, etc).
But somehow when i run the project i got this error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ExecutionException, java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "projectId" is null., Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "projectId" is null., Stacktrace: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nonnull field "projectId" is null.

I am using flutter 2.10.5 and firebase_core ^2.4.1

i have tried filling the options manually without the generated firebase_options but i still got the exact same error

Comment: try to reinitialize the project with `flutterfire config`

Comment: Yeah i reinitialize everything relating to firebase and it works!